# How to use React with p5.js

Tags: reactjs, p5.js

I really like p5.js and react.js so i wondered how to combine these two together, and i was unable to do it so I need your help. 
I cant really provide you with some code samples because I have no clue how to start.

So what I want to do :
1. create-react-app
2.render a canvas using p5.js (i dont need the p5.dom and p5.sound)

Comment: You can start by taking a look at [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-p5-wrapper) library.

Answer (score 11):

First thing that needs to be done is install the [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) tool. Once it's up and running the p5.js and the [react-p5-wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-p5-wrapper)  packages can be included; assuming a package manager like **npm** is being used, this can be done by executing `npm install p5 react-p5-wrapper` with whatever flags are considered necessary.

The react-p5-wrapper is a wrapper component that receives a reference ([instance mode](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode)) to the sketch and uses some of the react component "lifecycle methods" to manipulate it accordingly, mainly by executing a method called `myCustomRedrawAccordingToNewPropsHandler(props)` that needs to be defined within said sketch.

To give it a try and see it running, the contents of the *App.js* file could be modified like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import P5Wrapper from 'react-p5-wrapper';
import sketch from './sketches/sketch';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {color:[Math.random()*255, Math.random()*255, Math.random()*255]};
    this.randomColor = this.randomColor.bind(this);
  }

  randomColor(){
    this.setState({color:[Math.random()*255, Math.random()*255, Math.random()*255]}
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.randomColor}>Random Color</button>
        <P5Wrapper sketch={sketch} color={this.state.color}></P5Wrapper>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Where **`sketch`** is imported from *sketch.js* which is located in another folder, in this case called *sketches*:

```
export default function sketch(p){
    let canvas;

    p.setup = () => {
      canvas = p.createCanvas(300, 200);
      p.noStroke();
    }

    p.draw = () => {
      p.background('orangered');
      p.ellipse(150, 100, 100, 100);
    }

    p.myCustomRedrawAccordingToNewPropsHandler = (newProps) => {
      if(canvas) //Make sure the canvas has been created
        p.fill(newProps.color);
    }
}
```

If everything is working, a button and a sketch should be on screen and every time the button is pressed the circle in the sketch changes colors randomly.

It should be noted that the `myCustomRedrawAccordingToNewPropsHandler` function is called in the `componentDidMount` and the `componentWillReceiveProps` "lifecycle methods" of the wrapper, the latter being currently classified as [unsafe](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops).

Comment: Thanks Julian. This works perfectly! However if I want to use other additional add-on libraries eg: p5.sound, it'll not work?

Answer (score 8):

**react-p5**

This Component lets you integrate p5 Sketches into your React App.
[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-p5-o1qgc),
[Documentation](https://github.com/Gherciu/react-p5)

For [Advanced Usage](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/integrating-p5-sketches-into-your-react-app-de44a8c74e91) pls read this [Blog Post](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/integrating-p5-sketches-into-your-react-app-de44a8c74e91)

**Installation**

`npm i react-p5`

**Usage**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Sketch from "react-p5";

export default class App extends Component {
  x = 50
  y = 50

  setup = (p5, parent) => {
    p5.createCanvas(500, 500).parent(parent)
  }
  draw = p5 => {
    p5.background(0)
    p5.ellipse(this.x, this.y, 70, 70)
    this.x++
  }

  render() {
    return <Sketch setup={this.setup} draw={this.draw} />
  }
}
```

Comment: The reason you got downvoted is probably that you only pasted code without any explanation

Answer (score 5):

This can also be done without any third party library and function components.

**Installation :**

After running `create-react-app`, Install the p5 package using `npm install p5`.

**Code :**

In the `App.js` file

```
import './App.css';
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import p5 from 'p5';

function sketch(p) {
    // p is a reference to the p5 instance this sketch is attached to
    p.setup = function() {
        p.createCanvas(400, 400);
        p.background(0);
        p.circle(200, 200, 400);
    }

    p.draw = function() {
        // your draw code here
    }
}

function App() {
    // create a reference to the container in which the p5 instance should place the canvas
    const p5ContainerRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        // On component creation, instantiate a p5 object with the sketch and container reference 
        const p5Instance = new p5(sketch, p5ContainerRef.current);

        // On component destruction, delete the p5 instance
        return () => {
            p5Instance.remove();
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="App" ref={p5ContainerRef} />
    );
}

export default App;
```

**Further Explanation:**

When the `App` component gets created, it sets the reference `p5ContainerRef.current` to itself. The `useEffect` hook is run and creates a new p5 instance `p5Instance` with the `sketch` function and the containing node `p5ContainerRef.current` as parameters. By returning a function that runs `p5Instance.remove()`, the `p5Instance` is destroyed when the `App` component gets destroyed or re-rendered. This prevents having multiple p5 instances with their own canvases.

This code is showing what libraries like `react-p5` are doing in its core. They make sure a p5 instance is attached to a wrapper container and that p5 instances are destroyed when its wrapper component gets destroyed or re-rendered.

**Side note :**

You can rename the `App` component to something like `P5Component` and import it into any existing React App.

Comment: What about when we need render a component